# Deleting TableRow dynamically

Tags: android, onclicklistener, tablelayout, tablerow

I want to code a Table with some dynamic TableRows. 
Every TableRow has a "Row-Delete-Button" which delete the row in which the Button is. So every Button should delete its own TableRow.

For testing I tried my code with 2 hardcoded Rows:

```
tablerow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowelement,null,false);
table.addView(tablerow);

tablerow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowelement,null,false);
table.addView(tablerow);
```

Now I added an OnClickListener:

```
 DeleteButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);

   DeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View parentRow = (View)v.getParent();
            ViewGroup container = ((ViewGroup) parentRow.getParent());
            container.removeView(parentRow);
            container.invalidate();
        }
    });
```

With this code the OnClickListener only works for one (the first) TableRow.
Is there a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a listener for each delete button by using `findViewById` on each table row.

```
private class DeleteClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    private View row;

    public DeleteClickListener(View row) {
        this.row = row;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        table.removeView(row);
    }
}

private void setupTable() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
    View tablerow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowelement, table,false);
    Button deleteButton = (Button)tablerow.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new DeleteClickListener(tablerow));
    table.addView(tablerow);

    tablerow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowelement, table,false);
    deleteButton = (Button)tablerow.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new DeleteClickListener(tablerow));
    table.addView(tablerow);
}
```

Comment: You're right... I reached the goal some minutes ago by myself... Thank you anyway